# What happens if you bypass the load sharing FET in a Li-ion battery charger IC by connecting the input directly to the output pins?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, power-electronics, lithium-ion, lithium-polymer

I'm developing a lithium-ion battery (4.2V) charging circuit using the MPC73871 from Microchip - a linear charge IC with load sharing functionality. The output of the charging IC will feed into a TPS61202 boost converter to generate a 5V supply. I am considering releasing the design and PCB open source, but I have some reservations about it. In the specific application I'm designing for, there is a chance for the user to accidentally short circuit two nets together that would effectively bypass the load sharing circuitry all-together when a USB cable is plugged in. Here's the schematic:

[image]

The two points that can easily become connected are labelled USB and VIN in the schematic. You can see that if one were to short circuit these points together, 1) the output pins feed the input pins through the schottky diode D3 when a cable is not plugged in, and 2) the USB input connects directly to the output of the MCP when a cable *is* plugged in. I am trying to analyze what the effect of this error would be. This is a snippet of the functional block diagram from the datasheet on page 3.

(Datasheet link: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73871-Data-Sheet-20002090E.pdf)

[image]

And here is the chip behavior reference table, Table 4-1:

[image]

I believe for the case where the user *does not* have a USB cable inserted, the input voltage would be less than the output voltage due to the diode drop of D3. Thus, Vbat > Vin, and the system would be battery powered, referring to row 2 of the table. I don't believe this poses an issue, because the diode ensures the input voltage is always less than the output voltage. (Correct me if I am wrong)

However, if the user were to insert a USB cable to charge the battery while the system is still on, i.e. utilizing load sharing, that's where things get a bit muddy. I *believe* in this case, looking at Table 4-1, the conditions would be:

- Vin > Vbat
- Vin > 2V and UVLO
- CE = 1 (hard tied)
- Vbat < Vout

I think this would put the chip in the "IN powered, Charge possible" state (row 8), where the synchronous diode is off, the system power FET is on, and the charge FET is on/off depending on the battery voltage. But, I'm unsure if there are downsides to this. Does this screw up the battery charging algorithm?

**Main Question:** What negative effects would there be in the situation where the USB input to the MCP73871 is connected directly to the output, bypassing the load sharing circuit?

**Secondary Question:** Since I am considering releasing the board and schematic open source, and it utilizes a lithium-ion battery, I would like to make sure the circuit design is sound; is this schematic of generally sound design?

Design notes:

- D1 is a TVS diode for suppressing spikes on the USB input
- D3 is to drop the USB voltage down by ~400mV into the MCP73871. This is to remove some of the heat generation from the MCP itself, but also during load sharing, I found the TPS61202 boost converter will operate in DCM if the input voltage is too close to 5V. Dropping the voltage down with D3 keeps the boost converter in CCM, which is desirable for my application.
- I am using a 900mAh LiPo battery with a DW01 supervisor included on the assembly. My design sets the charge current at 400mA and the charge termination current at 100mA.
- I would like to cut-off the lithium-ion battery at 3.0V instead of the 2.45V threshold of the DW01. I would also like to prevent the TPS61202 from entering a bootloop sequence when the battery drops below 3.0V, and require the user to cycle the power switch before the system attempts to turn on again. To achieve this, instead of using something like the FS312, I use a TPS3840 with a latching circuit that holds the enable pin of the TPS61202 at GND when the voltage drops below 3.0V, until the user cycles the power switch. Explanation of the latching circuit can be found here: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva836a/snva836a.pdf

Thank you very much!